# Update a count variable in model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-1.3

What I want to do is simple I want to update the count variable of the object every time my view function is called.

My models is like this:

```
class Url(models.Model):
      #some vars here
      count=0

      def __unicode__(self):
            return self.urlx
      def incr(self):
            self.count+=1
```

and my view code is like this

```
@transaction.autocommit
def redirect(request,key):
    if(key):
        key='/'+key
        try:
            ob=Url.objects.get(urlx=key)
            ob.incr()  #not working
            ob.save()  #not working
            return HttpResponseRedirect(ob.url)
            val=ob.count
        except Url.DoesNotExist:
            key="Sorry! couldn't find that url"         

    return render_to_response('redir.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am sure I am overlooking something here, or is this not the correct way to do this?

Comment: You might also want to look at some code basics, after returning a value from a function no code is executed passed that point so val=ob.count is useless

Comment: @Hedde : sorry...i left it there...i was testing the try block earlier..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've missed out the "other vars here", it's not clear if you realize that Django model fields need to be, well, fields - that is, `models.CharField`, `models.IntegerField`, etc. Putting `count=0` just makes a class variable that won't be persisted in the database. You probably just want `count = models.IntegerField(default=0)`.